# Gridcell becomes non editable when it has validation errors

Tags: wpf, idataerrorinfo

I have implemented IDataErrorInfo to handle validation errors. Gridcell becomes textblock when it has validation errors.

[image]

Code : C#

```
 public class Customer :IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string sample;
    private string testpcode;

    public string SampleCode
    {
        get { return sample; ; }
        set { sample = value; OnPropertyChanged(SampleCode); }
    }
    public string TestPCode
    {
        get { return testpcode; }
        set { testpcode = value; OnPropertyChanged(TestPCode); }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(CheckCode());
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
    private string CheckCode()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.SampleCode))
        {
            return ("The sample code can't be empty");
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "SampleCode":
                    return CheckCode();
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml Code changes below for this UI:

```html
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ErrorTemplate">
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                </Border>
            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip"
          Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="grid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="20"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Click="AddButton_Click" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Add"/>
        <Button Click="DeleteButton_Click" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="Delete"/>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Grid.Row="2" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCollection}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SampleCode, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TestPCode}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>  
    </Grid>
```

Add a new row by click on the Add button and edit the cell of the newly added row. Then delete the selected item. Gricell becomes TextBlock. Not able to edit anything.

Comment: Please, share your xaml code and code behind as well